# phpmyadmin mysql error 1064 when creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

What could be wrong? I ran a DDL against MySQL , and its giving an error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR2(250) NOT NULL,
    BIO VARCHAR2(250) NOT NULL,
    ID NUMBER(10) NOT' at line 2`

Here's my DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE DW.BOOKS(    
BIO VARCHAR2( 250 ) NOT NULL ,
ID NUMBER( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
REVENUE VARCHAR2( 20 ) ,       
PRIMARY KEY ( ID )
);
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/win.920/a97249/ch3.htm#1026758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing oracle and MySQL. MySQL doesn't provide either `VARCHAR2` not `NUMBER`.

Please also see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/win.920/a97249/ch3.htm#1026758) page for [data types differences](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/win.920/a97249/ch3.htm#1026758) in Oracle and MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE DW.BOOKS(    
    BIO VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ,
    ID INT(10) NOT NULL ,
    REVENUE VARCHAR(20) ,       
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with "NUMBER(10)".  Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DW.BOOKS` (
  `BIO` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `REVENUE` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the [data type overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-overview.html) documentation. There are no `VARCHAR2` or `NUMBER` types in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKS(    
BIO VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL ,
ID int( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
REVENUE VARCHAR( 20 ) ,       
PRIMARY KEY ( ID )
);
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a4ce)